# 'HELP' with model.fit function in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, warnings

Here is the code:

```
initial_learning_rate = 0.0001
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True
)
model.compile(
loss="binary_crossentropy",
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
metrics=["acc"],
)
checkpoint_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
"3d_image_classification.h5", save_best_only=True
)
early_stopping_cb = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_acc", patience=15)
epochs = 100
model.fit(
train_dataset,
validation_data=validation_dataset,
epochs=epochs,
shuffle=True,
verbose=2,
callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb],
)
```

When I run it, it stops at "Epoch 1/100" and then displays a warning message like "WARNING: tensorflow:Autograph could not transform bound method Dense.call of keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x14145fd60 and will run It as-is. etc.."

Can you help me please??

Comment: That is just a warning, you can probably ignore it, I am not sure what help you need.

Comment: The problem is that nothing goes on, no result is produced after the warning message and it takes a lot.

Comment: now it produced a result for epoch 1/100 BUT it took 1223s instead of 12s, as predicted

Comment: Check [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37144#issuecomment-617373639) will give you what is all about this WARNING. Thanks!